# Trying to identify a book where women ruled the country

Tags: story-identification, novel

Can anyone identify this book please.

I read it in 1990 or 1991 and it was part of a series.

In the story the women were more powerful than men. I'm not sure if there were men in the land.

The queen and her sister had red hair (all the people might have had red hair). They lived in a castle. The sister called on the Loch Ness monster for help in a battle.

The Loch Ness monster part was near the end of the book so it wasn't a main character. It helped the sisters save the land or castle and then it said goodbye until next time it was called upon. This part of to the book seemed a bit daft.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Any of these? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_Monster_in_popular_culture#:~:text=It%20is%20a%20shapeshifting%20creature,Mist%20by%20Nancy%20Lee%20Badger.

Comment: In what way were the women more powerful? What was the battle about? Have a gander at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and if any new details come to mind, please [edit] them in

Comment: Thanks I've edited my question.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Was this book fiction or non fiction?:)

Comment: Fiction and it was part of a series of young adult fantasy.